# Use an Anonymous Stringstream to Construct a String

Tags: c++, string, sstream

I want to read directly into a string with code like this:

```
std::string myString(( std::ostringstream() << myInt << " "
                                            << myFloat << " "
                                            << std::boolalpha << myBool ).str());
```

But VS2012 is giving me a complaint that `basic_ostream` doesn't have an `str()` method.

Is there a way to do this with an anonymous stringstream?

Comment: This code compiles as-is and runs fine on Clang. (Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `operator<<` for streams returns `std::ostream &` which doesn't have `str()` member function. You need to use cast.

```
static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << etc).str()
```

---

### Differences between  C++03 and C++11 when using temporary stream!

### C++03

But be aware (in C++03) that `std::ostringstream()` creates a temporary object, which means the *non-member* overloads of `operator<<` cannot be invoked for the first `<<` because all of them accepts the first argument as `std::ostream&` which cannot bind to the temporary object. The temporary object will be able to invoke *only member* functions.

That means, the following would give you *address* instead of *string*:

```
static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << "XYZ").str()
```

Because the overload which takes `char const*` as argument *is a non-member function*, which cannnot be invoked, so the above code end up calling the member function which takes `void const*` as argument and thus `"XYZ"` is implicitly converted into `void const*`, which prints *address* of string literal.

Once the temporary invokes the member function, the remaining chained `<<` **may** invoke *non-member* overloads, because the member function return `std::ostream&` which *now* can bind to the first argument to the *non-member* overloads of `operator<<`. So this following code would print *an address* (instead of `"XYZ"`) followed by string `"ABC"`:

```
static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << "XYZ" << "ABC").str()
```

Online demo:

- [GCC output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e5740f22087996c) **without** `-std=c++11`
- [Clang output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f4da4d6629c34cb) **without**`-std=c++11`

### C++11

In C++11, this issue has been fixed by adding a non-member function (27.7.3.9) which takes the first argument as rvalue reference which then forwards the call to the appropriate function, either member or non-member. So it prints `XYZ` followed by `ABC`:

- [GCC output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39f7542a1c288828) **with**`-std=c++11`
- [Clang output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01709784ee8f6eec) **with** `-std=c++11`

Comment: The non-member overloads cannot be used for the first `<<`.  After that, you have the `ostream&` (non-const) which was returned by the first `<<`.  The usual solution is to start with `std::ostringstream().flush() << ...`.  `ostream::flush` is a member function which returns a `ostream&`, and of course, it won't actually do anything on a stream which you haven't yet written to.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I just came to know that there C++11 behaves differently in this case. So what I described before is true for C++03 only. With C++11, we don't need `flush()` trick anymore!

Comment: I seem to remember the same thing, but I can't find what has changed in the standard.   (I think it is somehow related to rvalue-references; I don't know why.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, 27.7.3.9 has introduced rvalue-references for output streams (and there is rvalue-references for input streams also).

Comment: @Nawaz I know that to Microsoft the standard is kind of a suggestion, but in Visual Studio 2010 I see your C++11 code work. I thought that Visual Studio 2010 was C++03?

Comment: Notice: latest clang++ compiler (9.0.0) complains about non-const lvalue reference so to cast we need `static_cast<const std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << etc).str()`

Comment: On MSVC 2019 it gives `error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from '_Ostr' to 'std::ostringstream &'
        with
        [
            _Ostr=std::ostringstream
        ]`, note: static_cast and safe_cast to reference can only be used for valid initializations or for lvalue casts between related classes. Note that @Krzysztof's solution above works.

Answer (score 8):

`basic_osstream::operator<<` returns a `basic_ostream`, not a `ostringstream`.  The compiler is not lying to you.

I would rather create a StringBuilder type device.

```
class StringBuilder
{
public:
    template <typename T> inline StringBuilder& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        mStream << t;
        return * this;
    }
    inline std::string get() const
    {
        return mStream.str();
    }
    inline operator std::string () const
    {
        return get();
    }
private:
    std::stringstream mStream;
};
```

Now you can:

```
std::string myString (StringBuilder() << myInt << " " << myFloat /*...*/);
```

There are also similar devices in Boost -- you would do well to use those instead if it is available to you.

Comment: FWIW: this would be my solution as well.

Comment: What is the **similar** device in boost. Am looking for it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and John answer seems fine, thanks a lot! - I tried to build a string by using the operator '<<' onto a 'stringstream', and it did compiled & worked fine with 'clang' on macOS but not with 'gcc' on ubuntu, (compiling with -std=c++11 on modern updated compilers), it looks like in the Mac machine the operator is returning a stringstream instead of a basic_ostream......

Here is a minimal program which does not compiles with g++ but compiles with clang (experimental concepts), as tested in the Compiler Explorer (godbolt.org):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   using namespace std;
   cout << ((stringstream() << "hola").str()) << endl ;
}
```