# Can a temporary stringstream object be used?

Tags: c++, c++11

This works:

```
stringstream temp;
temp << i;
result_stream << transform(temp.str());
```

(`transform` is a function that takes a `string` and returns a `string`; `i` is an `int`).  However, my attempt to let C++11 create a temporary object without a name didn't work:

```
result_stream << transform((stringstream() << i).str());
```

I thought it would work, since the second `<<` should just return the first argument and I'd be able to use `str()` on that.  But I get this error:

```
error: 'class std::basic_ostream<char>' has no member named 'str'
```

I'm using g++ 4.8.1 (MinGW-W64).

Is there a way to accomplish this (i.e. write code like this using an unnamed temporary)?  (The above code is a bit simplified, and the actual code involves using `<<` on arguments other than `int`.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use an Anonymous Stringstream to Construct a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665458/use-an-anonymous-stringstream-to-construct-a-string)

Comment: Is that specifically a C++11 question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This doesn't work because the second `<<` is `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, int);` and so the return type is `ostream&` which has no member `str()`.

You would have to write:

```
result_stream << transform( static_cast<stringstream &>(stringstream() << i).str() );
```

---

*Update (2019):* According to [LWG 1203](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1203) the standard may be changed in future (and one major implementation already has) so that this code no longer works, and a simpler code works instead. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325270/error-when-casting-temporary-object-to-non-const-reference) for detail.

In the interim period, apparently the following works on both old and new:

```
result_stream << transform( static_cast<stringstream &>(stringstream().flush() << i).str() );
//                                                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

This *should* not be a performance penalty since flushing an empty stream has no effect...

Comment: Thanks, that works.  But it's starting to look a little hairy, and it doesn't work when `i` is replaced by an expression of my own class, for which I had defined a friend `operator<<`.  So I probably won't pursue this any further.

Comment: Notice: latest clang++ compiler (9.0.0) complains about non-const lvalue reference so to cast we need  `static_cast<const stringstream &>(stringstream() << i).str()`

Comment: @Krzysztof [works fine in 9.0.0](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/VenbjY), maybe your code was different

Comment: @M.M Sorry, I have not mentioned that I was using MacOS. I have copy-pasted your code and compiler gives me error `x.cc:12:24: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'basic_stringstream<...>' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'basic_stringstream<...>'
    cout << transform( static_cast<stringstream &>(stringstream() << i).str() );` With g++ 9.2.0 it compiles without any problem.

Comment: @Krzysztof sounds like a compiler bug, I would suggest posting a new question that includes the reproducible example, in case we are both overlooking something new in the standard .  (you can refer to this answer in your question if you like)

Comment: @M.M I have created new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325270/error-when-casting-temporary-object-to-non-const-reference) about that problem.

Comment: @Krzysztof the LWG report suggests adding a `.flush()` to make the code work on both stdlib implementations, i.e. `transform( static_cast<stringstream &>(stringstream().flush() << i).str() )` -- does that work for you? If so then I will add it to my answer

Answer (score 6):

The result of the `<<` operator on the temporary `stringstream` is an `ostream`. There is no `str()` method on an `ostream`.

Use `to_string` instead:

```
using std::to_string;

result_stream << transform(to_string(i));
```

You can define a helper `to_string` to handle objects not covered by `std::to_string`.

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_string (const T &t) {
   std::ostringstream oss;
   oss << t;
   return oss.str();
}
```

For example, if you had a class `Foo` that understood redirection to an `ostream`, and `f` was an instance of `Foo`, then you could do:

```
result_stream << transform(to_string(f));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHLasMwELzrKxYXHLmkodBbnPrYD2hzLBijyKkglox2dSjF3@7qFaeGHOqDkXZHszOzYhyfzkLMD0qLiztJOCiDZGU3NOxWwzslskqfG8b8wQmCd4nuQh8RBz8MYF0pwYzSdmQsHA7AkU77faIArBLef7EsjKMAKmwk2EMRbhh@m0@9qTPWSnJWwyN9KYy1iU2QnrRJbh3E3eaQ7TT2xg73x2c@3CmN0hJ/3kLRNA0UVc2mxeabMQneWyX1KSnOid01ufQMbkEYjYmj7G@u82QTLRa@W1z91GwmOYyXjnzi9D1K3Q0Sjs3al2nziSf@I5SU2RcJvp2FGExxpayljVrbtndatO0qZI8Md6rZX5G480Q8haI0wdApDTzPCwUFr/AS3wSjvd@CPzqMWYeZi97UWa0szrvuiS9Irqqq/je4D2Avb55/AQ)

If you actually want to use a lot of redirection to build up a string before transforming, you could create a helper object for that as well.

```
struct to_string_stream {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    template <typename T>
    auto & operator << (const T &t) { oss << t; return *this; }
    operator std::string () const { return oss.str(); }
    void clear () { oss.string(std::string()); }
};
```

Then, you could do something like:

```
to_string_stream tss;
result_stream << transform(tss << i << ':' << f);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLLasMwELzrKxYXErukodCbnfjYL8ixEIQspwJba6R1oYR8u6uXnTQN1IfY2ZnZnVlJDMPLSYjpSWnRjY2EnUJLRvK@ZteafVAio/SpZsx9jILgzADAUlOWSQ8rwEEaTmhgt4M8YFEFtoh89xhJo9FRKXAkz82MtGNHJWT@n/U/6w@9rrzkwi4Q4WOcU3kL19ZkuLYtmv7xxHncVmkrDeWvG8jquoasqNhlCfOOGOmtUVI3/@daMLQbEKht7LFq/wTFECdzaDbnqdiU5hIeo9@ULYmXEQ5JAFob5ECyHzpO7kToe5Ca9xIOdUD4SHhvNlo7wIqcMd/EV6mazT3Tp7KV8@T1i/B2j3mR4p2vgezWgXkx675QNSA6yY1nnxfCTZu8CGyXnClN0HOlA9frfUHBHt5CPr/F1tF80vvlUNrBr@sQAs13IKeYUIUrVK79q3Un7Y56mn4A)

Answer (score 6):

`operator<<()` returns a reference to the base class `std::ostream` contained within the `std::stringstream`. The base class doesn't contain the `str()` method. You can cast it back down to a `std::stringstream&`:

```
result_stream << transform(static_cast<std::stringstream&>(std::stringstream() << i).str());
```

Answer (score 5):

Tried and failed to do this for C++11 (in 2009):

http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#1203

libc++ went outlaw and implemented it anyway.

It is up for reconsideration, but can not possibly be standardized prior to 2017 (standardization is a glacial process).