# Error when casting temporary object to non-const reference

Tags: c++, clang++

Here is a reproducible example taken from question about [using temporary stringstream object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391205/can-a-temporary-stringstream-object-be-used/27391248#comment104844676_27391248):

```
#include <sstream>                     
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

std::string transform(std::string);

int main()
{
    int i{};
    cout << transform( static_cast<stringstream &>(stringstream() << i).str() );
}
```

When trying to compile with *clang version 9.0.0* under MacOS High Sierra I got following error:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 x.cc -c
x.cc:12:24: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'basic_stringstream<...>' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'basic_stringstream<...>'
    cout << transform( static_cast<stringstream &>(stringstream() << i).str() );
                       ^                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

When g++ 9.2.0 is used on same machine (also on Linux) everything compiles fine.

Seems that changing cast from `stringstream &` to `const stringstream &` or to `stringstream &&` solves problem.

The question is if this is compiler bug or maybe clang is more strict about some standard rules?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/fb_DR2)...

Comment: FWIW, if you just need a single thing converted, `transform(std::to_string(i))` works and IMHO is easier to understand.

Comment: @MaxLanghof IIRC godbolt uses libstdc++ for clang instead of libc++.  It reproduces on wandbox: https://wandbox.org/permlink/mwEqfxr8hW7uhx4w

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica True, with the `stdlib=libc++` it fails: https://godbolt.org/z/4iMPgc.

Comment: not the problem but `using namespace std;` + `std::string transform(std::string);` will cause confusion sooner or later

Comment: I don't understand why you are even trying to turn a temporary (which may be dropped via RAII) into a lvalue reference. If you really do need lvalue reference you should store into a variable. I don't see any reason for the cast at all in fact. (what does .str() return, a view or a string?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think that is a bug in libc++.

According to [[ostream.rvalue]](https://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.rvalue) there is an overload:

```
template<class charT, class traits, class T>
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>&& os, const T& x);
```

[But libc++ implements this similar to](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/ostream#L1031):

```
template <class _Stream, class _Tp>
enable_if_t</*...*/, _Stream&&>
operator<<(_Stream&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
{
    // ...
}
```

The implementation makes this overload a better candidate than the in-class `operator<<` of `ostream` in overload resolution if a stream rvalue is used with `<<`, while the signature in the standard wouldn't be, and it also returns a rvalue reference, when it should return a lvalue reference. It also returns a reference of same type as was passed to it, while it should return a reference to its `ostream` base class, according to the standard quote.

The rvalue reference can not be bound to a non-const lvalue reference, hence the error.

The bug has already been reported [here](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20596) and there is an open LWG issue regarding the behavior [here](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1203), which seems to suggest that in the future the standard might be adjusted to mandate libc++'s current behavior.

Comment: So this would be a breaking change for all the code out there implementing the workaround in the question (this happens with fstreams too) ... I wonder if it is possible to return something that can be cast to lvalue reference and rvalue reference so that old code doesn't break

Answer (score 1):

The answer to that is a different implementation of ostream insertion between libstdc++ and libc++.

The implementation is almost the same, but libc++ implementation has following code in it (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/ostream):

```
template <class _Stream, class _Tp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
typename enable_if
<
    !is_lvalue_reference<_Stream>::value &&
    is_base_of<ios_base, _Stream>::value,
    _Stream&&
>::type
operator<<(_Stream&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
{
    __os << __x;
    return _VSTD::move(__os);
}
```

This grabs the rvalue `strstream` you create in situ and  returns an rvalue, to which lvalue reference can't bind.

On the other hand, libstdc++ [implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/ostream) has following:

```
 template<typename _Ostream>
    using __rvalue_ostream_type =
      typename __is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<
    _Ostream>::__ostream_type;


  template<typename _Ostream, typename _Tp>
    inline
    typename enable_if<__and_<__not_<is_lvalue_reference<_Ostream>>,
                  __is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Ostream>,
                  __is_insertable<
                __rvalue_ostream_type<_Ostream>,
                const _Tp&>>::value,
               __rvalue_ostream_type<_Ostream>>::type
    operator<<(_Ostream&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
    {
      __rvalue_ostream_type<_Ostream> __ret_os = __os;
      __ret_os << __x;
      return __ret_os;
```

Where __rvalue_ostream_type after some magic becomes not an r-value reference. Thus code compiles.

The above is a bug in libstdc++ and can be submitted as a bug report.

Comment: It does not seem that there is any point reporting it. It has already been reported and there is an open LWG issue regarding this behavior, see my answer.