# Understanding Alias Templates

Tags: c++, templates, alias, enable-if, c++17

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30189926/2642059) that has several references to the code:

```
template <typename...>
using void_t = void;
```

I believe I have a generally misunderstand [alias templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

**Why wouldn't you just evaluate whatever template parameter you're passing into an alias template in an `enable_if_t` or `conditional_t` statement?**

Is the code above just about doing an `enable_if_t` on multiple template parameters at once?

Secondly, I believe that I have a specific misunderstanding of the role of `void_t`. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189926/metaprograming-failure-of-function-definition-defines-a-separate-function/30197624?noredirect=1#comment48490606_30190799) states that the C++17 standard defines `void_t`. Here's what I don't get:

**Isn't `void_t` just an arbitrary name? If I still have to define `template <typename...> using void_t = void;` wherever I plan to use `void_t` what's the point of standardizing an arbitrary name?**

Comment: Yes, `void_t` is just an arbitrary name. But if it were standardized, it'd be spelled `std::void_t` so that you wouldn't have to define it yourself. Same reason `std::enable_if` and other type traits are standardized - so that other programmers would recognize them and all of use wouldn't have to keep redefining all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the shown example really shows what `void_t` is good for as it only shows one use case, but when you look at

```
template<typename T>
struct has_to_string<T, 
    void_t<decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>()))>
    > 
: std::true_type { };
```

it is not so much different from

```
template<typename T>
struct has_to_string<T, 
    decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>()), void())
    > 
: std::true_type { };
```

And for this statement:

> The former version is much easier to read and `void_t` doesn't require `decltype` to work.

I think the advantage in readability is quite small and the second part makes no sense, when `decltype` doesn't work, SFINAE kicks in as expected.

One example where `void_t` is more useful is the one from the proposal:

```
// primary template handles types that have no nested ::type member
template< class, class = void_t<> >
struct has_type_member
: std::false_type { };

// specialization recognizes types that do have a nested ::type member
template< class T >
struct has_type_member<T, void_t<typename T::type>>
: std::true_type { }
```

As you can see, even the primary template uses `void_t` to increase the readability as it now matches the specialization. That is not strictly necessary, but I like it. The real power comes when you think about the alternatives. Without `void_t`, the specialization is now more complicated:

```
template< class T >
struct has_type_member<T, decltype(typename T::type, void())>
: std::true_type { }
```

wouldn't work as `T::type` names a type, not an expression. You therefore need

```
template< class T >
struct has_type_member<T, decltype(std::declval<typename T::type>(), void())>
: std::true_type { }
```

The whole expression becomes longer, more tricky and it might suffer from edge-cases you forgot to handle. This is where `void_t` really helps, the other uses are then just a small improvement and they increase consistency.

Comment: I can see how this would be really useful for variadic templates as well.

Comment: @JonathanMee And more... the variadic nature of `void_t` itself even allows for multiple conditions at once, think `void_t<typename T::value_type,decltype(std::declval<T>().begin()),decltype(std::declval<T>().end())>`.

Answer (score 9):

In Barry's example from your linked question:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_to_string
: std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct has_to_string<T, 
    void_t<decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>()))>
    > 
: std::true_type { };
```

`void_t` is just used to translate the type deduced by `decltype` to `void` so that it matches the default argument to the *primary* template definition. The SFINAE is all taken care of by the `decltype` expression. You could just as easily do the following:

```
//use , void() instead of wrapping in void_t
//this uses the comma operator to check the type of the to_string call, then change the type to void
decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>()), void())
```

The former version is much easier to read and `void_t` doesn't require `decltype` to work.

If `void_t` is available in your implementation you don't need to redefine it. When it's standardised it will be available just like any of the other alias templates in the standard.

Think about it this way: if `T` is `int`, which has a valid `std::to_string` overload, deduction will look like this:

`has_to_string<int>` -> `has_to_string<int,void>` because of the default argument. So lets look for specializations of `has_to_string` with those arguments.

```
template<typename T>
struct has_to_string<T, 
    void_t<decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>()))>
    > 
: std::true_type { };
```

Okay, that is a partial specialization for some `T` and some dependent type. Let's work out that type:

```
void_t<decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>()))>
//std::to_string(int&&) is valid and returns a std::string
void_t<std::string>
//void_t changes types to void
void
```

Now our specialization looks like this:

```
template<>
struct has_to_string<int,void>
: std::true_type { };
```

This matches our instantiation of `has_string<int,void>`, so `has_to_string<int>` inherits from `std::true_type`.

Now think about it when `T` is `struct Foo{};`. Again, let's work out that dependent type:

```
void_t<decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>()))>
//wait, std::to_string(Foo&&) doesn't exist
//discard that specialization
```

With that specialization discarded, we fall back to the primary template:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_to_string
: std::false_type { };
```

So `has_to_string<Foo>` inherits from `std::false_type`.

Comment: So you're saying that `template <typename...> using void_t = void;` will be defined in one of the standard headers?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Then you'll just `#include<type_traits>` and use `std::void_t`.

Comment: @JonathanMee It should make into C++17. [Proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4436.pdf).

Comment: @TartanLlama So I think I understand: I can't use `enable_if_t` cause there is no "if_this_compiles" meta function, and I'd need that to do: `enable_if_t<if_this_compiles<to_string(T::type)>::value, void>` So effectively, I'm using `void_t` as an `enable_if_t` with an "if_this_compiles" condition and a `void` return type.

Comment: Effectively, but with this construct `decltype` does the SFINAE and `void_t` supports it.

Comment: @TartanLlama OK, one more question and I think I'll understand your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30309643/2642059