# Is There a Version decltype That Takes Two Parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, arguments, decltype

As far as I can tell `decltype` takes one argument: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

However, [TartanLlama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496161/tartanllama) has answered two of my questions using a `decltype` call which took two parameters:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30190317/2642059
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30302586/2642059

I see that code compile and run as TartanLlama states it will, but I don't understand how a two argument `decltype` call should behave.

Can someone provide me a reference for what two argument `decltype` should do?

Comment: @MikeSeymour That is indeed an exact duplicate. I'm not sure if I understand the application of the comma operator fully though. In a Substitution Failure Is Not An Error context it makes sense, but [AndyProwl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1932150/andy-prowl) gives an example of the comma operator in a `static_assert` what happens if the left hand side fails? Does it just always return the right hand side irrespectively?

Comment: If it's not in a SFINAE context, you'd simply get an error.