# Why does Member Detector fallback have to be int?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I thought I was getting the idea of this class (from here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector):

```
template<typename T>
class DetectX
{
    struct Fallback { int X; }; // add member name "X"
    struct Derived : T, Fallback { };

    template<typename U, U> struct Check;

    typedef char ArrayOfOne[1];  // typedef for an array of size one.
    typedef char ArrayOfTwo[2];  // typedef for an array of size two.

    template<typename U> 
    static ArrayOfOne & func(Check<int Fallback::*, &U::X> *);

    template<typename U> 
    static ArrayOfTwo & func(...);

  public:
    typedef DetectX type;
    enum { value = sizeof(func<Derived>(0)) == 2 };
};
```

but I tried to adapt it to my case in which I was looking for a member `double MyTest`. So I changed this line:

```
struct Fallback { int X; }; // add member name "X"
```

to

```
struct Fallback { double MyTest; };
```

but the detector was returning "true" for all classes regardless of if they had a MyTest member or not. I changed the line to:

```
struct Fallback { int MyTest; };
```

and then it worked as expected.

Can anyone explain why the fallback has to be an int rather than the type of the member you are actually looking for?

Here is an example where I look for X as an int but Y as a double:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector

// Standard point representation
struct Point3
{
    double X,Y,Z;
};

struct SomethingElse{};

template<typename T>
class DetectX
{
    struct Fallback { int X; }; // add member named "X"
    struct Derived : T, Fallback { };

    template<typename U, U> struct Check;

    typedef char ArrayOfOne[1];  // typedef for an array of size one.
    typedef char ArrayOfTwo[2];  // typedef for an array of size two.

    template<typename U>
    static ArrayOfOne & func(Check<int Fallback::*, &U::X> *);

    template<typename U>
    static ArrayOfTwo & func(...);

  public:
    typedef DetectX type;
    enum { value = sizeof(func<Derived>(0)) == 2 };
};

template<typename T>
class DetectY
{
    struct Fallback { double Y; }; // add member named "Y"
    struct Derived : T, Fallback { };

    template<typename U, U> struct Check;

    typedef char ArrayOfOne[1];  // typedef for an array of size one.
    typedef char ArrayOfTwo[2];  // typedef for an array of size two.

    template<typename U>
    static ArrayOfOne & func(Check<double Fallback::*, &U::X> *);

    template<typename U>
    static ArrayOfTwo & func(...);

  public:
    typedef DetectY type;
    enum { value = sizeof(func<Derived>(0)) == 2 };
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << DetectX<Point3>::value << " " << DetectX<SomethingElse>::value << std::endl;

  std::cout << DetectY<Point3>::value << " " << DetectY<SomethingElse>::value << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

My output is:

1 0

1 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't have to be `int`. It can be of any type. You just have to refer to it correctly, by type and name, in every place:

```
using Arbitrary = double;

struct Fallback { Arbitrary X; }; // <== arbitrary type, specific name X
```

*and* here:

```
template<typename U> 
static ArrayOfOne & func(Check<Arbitrary Fallback::*, &U::X> *);
//                             ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑                ↑↑↑
//                             this type              this name
```

The idea is that if `T` doesn't have an `X`, you'll find `Fallback::X`, which will match `&U::X` by type (since there's only one - the one in `Fallback`). But if `T` does have an `X`, the lookup will be ambiguous. So it doesn't matter what type `Fallback::X` has - `int` is just the shortest one.

Note that in C++11, this is a lot easier with something like Yakk's `can_apply`:

```
template <class T>
using x_type = decltype(&T::X);

template <class T>
using has_x = can_apply<x_type, T>;
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30189926/2069064) for a half dozen other ways that are all better than the old-style member detector.

Comment: I now get that it shouldn't matter which type it is, but it still doesn't seem to work with 'double' (see my example in my recent edit).

Comment: @DavidDoria Because you have `&U::X` where you need to have `&U::Y`.

Comment: Wow, you mean I have to type the right thing for the compiler to know what I want!? Sorry for the noise...

Comment: Perhaps I found out why this is a bad method - I tried `class X{}; cout << DetectX<X>::value;` and it was 1!? Does that make sense? That if the class has a member named 'X' OR the class name itself is 'X' it will return true?

Comment: @DavidDoria That's called injected class name.