# Is it possible to check for existence of member templates just by an identifier?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, type-traits

Can we detect member `function template`, `variable template`,  `class`/`struct`/`union template` or `alias template` without knowing amount, or nature of `template`/`non-template` parameters?

When I try to think about this, nothing really comes to my mind. But let's have structure with member function template:

```
struct foo
{
    // Really random. Let's assume we don't know this declaration, just the name "bar"
    template <class T, std::size_t N, class... Args>
    void bar(T a, T b, T(&c)[N], Args const& ...);
};
```

How do I check if the `foo::bar` template exists?

Instantiation-based type traits don't apply here, because (theoretically) we don't have knowledge of *which parameters we should use*, *in what order* and *how many of them*. Maybe some magic lookup method would be appropriate? Or maybe it's just impossible?

---

When searching, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552637/use-sfinae-to-detect-the-existence-of-a-templated-member-function), but solutions in the answers require knowledge about nature of `template`.

---

Here is my first **failed** attempt for detecting `struct template`:

```
struct foo
{
    template<class T>
    struct bar { };
};

template <class T, class = void>
struct has_template_bar : std::false_type
{ };

template <class T>
struct has_template_bar <T, void> : std::true_type
{
    template<template<class...> class tplt_tplt = T::bar> // Invalid default argument
    struct placebo
    { };
};
```

Comment: If there are two such methods, I guess you also want it to return true?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid That would be great! But I'm afraid that adding possibility of overloading might complicate things even more.

Comment: I'm sure I saw an answer to this just a few days ago, which also covered the overload case. Can't find it now though. I'll keep looking!

Comment: It (let me say) _doesn't exist_ until you specialize it. Do you want to detect if it exists `bar<void, 0, int>`, as an example?

Comment: @skypjack I partially know how to implement it when I know what I can use as arguments, but the problem arises when I don't know if I can use template template argument, type argument or non-type argument, and if the count of arguments is correct.

Comment: @skypjack I thought about your comment. I don't think you can simply detect `TemplateFoo`, as it's not a type but a meta-type (used to generate types). So I don't see any way of specializing on it.

Comment: @vsoftco That's what I'm saying. He cannot detect something that _doesn't exist_ yet, unless by giving it the births. I guess the OP wants to detect if at least a specialization exists, no matter what. Am I wrong? The question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @skypjack Although you can have stuff like `template<template<class...>class> bool f(){return true;}` what will identify meta-types. The problem is that you cannot overload/specialize.

Comment: @vsoftco This question is somehow intriguing indeed, if we are going to discuss about member methods.

Comment: The answers here are very different from each other, and make me worry that I don't even understand the question. What is the actual question such a trait would answer? "Is there at least one method called `bar`, which may or may not be a template?" ***or*** "Ignoring non-template methods, is there at least one template method called bar?" ***or*** something else entirely?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Well, I try to think simply about this :) The original idea is: check if structure has declared (possibly overloaded, that came later) member template (of listed kinds). Your answer is probably closest to that - I mean you can detect templates by their names alone, and thats great. The problem is that this method doesn't distinguish between templates and non-templates (not a big problem in my point of view, basic idea is completed). Bigger drawback is that checked structure cannot be `final` (because you derieve from it).

Answer (score 5):

I can show you how to detect a struct template:

```
template < class > struct check_template : std::false_type {};

// Specialize for template classes
template <template<class...> class X, class... Args>
struct check_template< X<Args...> > : std::true_type {};
```

You can then probably play around with `declval`, `void_t`, etc. to detect member templates.

In case you want to detect types vs. meta-types, i.e. templates like `std::vector` and not `std::vector<int>`, you can do the following:

```
#include <iostream>

template <template<class...> class>
constexpr bool is_template()
{
    return true;
}

template <class>
constexpr bool is_template()
{
    return false;
}

struct Foo{};

template<class>
struct TemplateFoo{};

int main()
{
     std::cout << std::boolalpha;
     std::cout << is_template<Foo>() << std::endl;
     std::cout << is_template<TemplateFoo>() << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebdd7e31c43c03a2)

Note that the solutions won't work if the meta-type has any non-type parameters, like

```
template<class, int> struct X{};
```

Comment: Both the solutions won't work with types like `template<int> struct R {};`.

Comment: @skypjack That's right. However I have no idea how one can get this done when you have type/non-type mixing and you don't know anything about them.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't say I have idea of that, but it could be something to mention for the reader. That's all. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack Mentioned it :)

Answer (score 4):

This approach works in the presence of multiple overloads, returning `false_type` if and only if there are no methods, or members, called `bar`. It doesn't tell us anything useful about what the `bar`(s) is/are though (more on that later).

***(Note: This answer (and question?) are dupes. I learned about this technique on SO only a few days ago. But I can't find the original!)***

This uses `void_t`, which you may need to define yourself (not in c++11, for example):

```
template<typename ...T>
struct voider { using type = void; };
template<typename ...T>
using void_t = typename voider<T...> :: type;
```

`bar` is the member we are interested in, so we make a really boring struct with a member called bar:

```
struct just_a_bar { int bar; };
```

Then a template, given `T`, which declares a struct that inherits from both `T` and `just_a_bar`.

```
template<typename T>
struct MultipleBars : public T , public just_a_bar { };
```

Now, `decltype(MultipleBars<T>::bar)` will give an ambiguity error if, and only if, there is a member `bar` in T. We can use this:

```
template<typename T, typename =void>
struct has_at_least_one_bar : public true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_at_least_one_bar<T, void_t< decltype(MultipleBars<T>::bar) >>
    : public false_type { 
};
```

---

Then, to use the above for real:

```
struct zero { };
struct one { 
    void bar(int,int);
};
struct two { 
    //template<typename P, typename Q> // works fine with templates too
    void bar(int);
    void bar(int,int);
};


int main() { 
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << has_at_least_one_bar<zero>{} << endl; // false
    cout << has_at_least_one_bar<one>{} << endl;  // true
    cout << has_at_least_one_bar<two>{} << endl;  // true
}
```

---

Once you know `bar` exists, you probably want more detail. If you have a few specific patterns in mind (non-template member, template method with  type parameters only, template method with two `int` non-type parameters, template method with three template-template parameters, ...) then I think you can test for each of those patterns individually. But ultimately there are limits to what you can detect with a finite number of such patterns. (And the fact that you mean templated methods, not templated structs, might make this more difficult

Comment: What should be the template argument when calling `has_at_least_one_bar`? When I try `just_a_bar`, then `MultipleBars` derieves twice from it.

Comment: I forgot to add an example of usage. I've just added some examples now. `just_a_bar` is an implementation detail of this trait. We need a 'dummy' type that has a (useless) `bar` method/member.

Comment: Why not simply `template<typename ...> using void_t = void;`? I think the need for an intermediate `struct` was due to a defect in standard, but now the simple definition should work.

Comment: Oh, so to detect underlying template, it would require to provide `3^n` (template template, type and non-type parameters) overloads (I'm still not sure about these), for example for max. 10 arguments, 59049 overloads would be required - and that just for one small `bar` ;)

Comment: @vsoftco, correct about `void_t`. Actually, did any versions of g++,clang,MSVC have a faulty implementation of that? If not, then I'd happily trust it. I don't want to trip up one SO user who happens to be on the wrong version of their compiler

Answer (score 3):

In C++14, you can use template variables to detect if a type is a specialization:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename>
constexpr bool is_spec = false;

template<template<typename...> class T, typename... U>
constexpr bool is_spec<T<U...>> = true;

struct S {};
template<typename> struct R {};

int main() {
    static_assert(not is_spec<S>, "!");
    static_assert(is_spec<R<void>>, "!");
}
```

Note that it won't work if non-type parameters are involved (as an example `template<int> struct R {};`).

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it. Thanks to [Aaron McDaid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39812189/5405086) and [vsoftco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39811961/5405086) answers, I succeeded in detecting member type templates (`alias template`, `struct template`, `class template` and `union template`), `member function templates` with one additional drawback, and `member variable templates`.

This implementation has some drawbacks:

- Class `foo` that we check for existence of name `bar` musn't be `final` type.
- Templates with mixed type/non-type/template-template parameters won't be detected.
- Code is kinda long.

Additional drawback is:

- [Note: Will be fixed soon!] Checking for `member function tempalates` will return `true`, if class `foo` has any overloaded function `bar`. I just didn't have any means to detect overloaded function alone. This will also affect final `has_member_template` type trait.

Here is the implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iomanip>

/***Check if type is template***/
template <template<class...> class>
constexpr bool is_template_type()
{
    return true;
}

template <class>
constexpr bool is_template_type()
{
    return false;
}

/***Check if T has static member function "bar" ***/
template <class, class = void>
struct has_static_member_function_bar : std::false_type
{ };

template <class T>
struct has_static_member_function_bar<T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_function<typename std::remove_pointer<decltype(&T::bar)>::type>::value
        >
    > : std::true_type
{ };

/***Check if T has member function "bar" ***/
template <class, class = void>
struct has_member_function_bar : std::false_type
{ };


template <class T>
struct has_member_function_bar<T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::bar)>::value
        >
    > : std::true_type
{ };

/***Check if T has member reference "bar" ***/
template <class, class = void>
struct has_member_reference_bar : std::false_type
{ };

template <class T>
struct has_member_reference_bar<T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_reference<decltype(T::bar)>::value
        >
    > : std::true_type
{ };

/***Check if T has static member object "bar" ***/
template <class, class = void>
struct has_static_member_object_bar : std::false_type
{ };

template <class T>
struct has_static_member_object_bar<T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_object<typename std::remove_pointer<decltype(&T::bar)>::type>::value &&
                    (!std::is_member_object_pointer<decltype(&T::bar)>::value)

        >
    > : std::true_type
{ };

/***Check if T has member function "bar" ***/
template <class, class = void>
struct has_member_object_bar : std::false_type
{ };

template <class T>
struct has_member_object_bar<T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_object_pointer<decltype(&T::bar)>::value
        >
    > : std::true_type
{ };

/***Check if T has member alias, struct, class, union template "bar" ***/
template <class, class = void>
struct has_member_type_template_bar : std::false_type
{ };

template <class T>
struct has_member_type_template_bar<T,
    std::enable_if_t<is_template_type<T::template bar>()
        >
    > : std::true_type
{ };

/***Check if T has at least one name "bar" ***/
struct has_at_least_one_bar_impl { int bar; };

template<typename T>
struct bar_overloads : T , has_at_least_one_bar_impl { };

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_at_least_one_bar : std::true_type { };

template<typename T>
struct has_at_least_one_bar<T, std::void_t< decltype(bar_overloads<T>::bar) >>
    : std::false_type { };

/***Check if T has member object, reference, not-overloaded function "bar" ***/
template <class, class = void>
struct has_non_type_non_overloaded_member_bar : std::false_type
{ };

template <class T>
struct has_non_type_non_overloaded_member_bar<T,
    std::void_t<decltype((void)(T::bar))>> : std::true_type
{ };


/***Check if T has member function "bar" ***/
template <class, class = void>
struct has_type_member_bar : std::false_type
{ };

template <class T>
struct has_type_member_bar<T,
    std::void_t<typename T::bar>> : std::true_type
{ };

/***Check if T has no more than one member "bar" ***/
template<class, class = void, class = void>
struct has_at_most_one_bar : std::false_type
{ };

template<class T>
struct has_at_most_one_bar<T,
    std::enable_if_t<
        has_type_member_bar<T>::value ||
        has_non_type_non_overloaded_member_bar<T>::value
        >
    > : std::true_type
{ };

/***Check if T has member function template "bar" ***/
template <class, class = void>
struct has_member_function_template_bar : std::false_type
{ };

template <class T>
struct has_member_function_template_bar<T,
    std::enable_if_t<has_at_least_one_bar<T>::value &&
        (!has_member_type_template_bar<T>::value) &&
        (!has_non_type_non_overloaded_member_bar<T>::value) &&
        (!has_member_function_bar<T>::value) &&
        (!has_type_member_bar<T>::value)
        >
    > : std::true_type
{ };

/***Check if T has member variable template "bar" ***/
template <class, class = void>
struct has_member_variable_template_bar : std::false_type
{ };

template <class T>
struct has_member_variable_template_bar<T,
    std::enable_if_t<has_at_least_one_bar<T>::value &&
        (!has_member_type_template_bar<T>::value) &&
        (!has_member_function_template_bar<T>::value) &&
        (!has_type_member_bar<T>::value) &&
        (!has_static_member_function_bar<T>::value) &&
        (!has_member_function_bar<T>::value) &&
        (!has_member_object_bar<T>::value) &&
        (!has_member_reference_bar<T>::value) &&
        (!has_static_member_object_bar<T>::value)>
    > : std::true_type
{ };

/***Check if T has any member template "bar" ***/
template <class, class = void>
struct has_member_template_bar : std::false_type
{ };

template <class T>
struct has_member_template_bar<T,
    std::enable_if_t<has_member_type_template_bar<T>::value ||
        has_member_function_template_bar<T>::value ||
        has_member_variable_template_bar<T>::value>
    > : std::true_type
{ };
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29645cfad6c76c17)

Example output:

```
---Has type template bar---
consists_no_bar:                  false
consists_alias:                   false
consists_struct:                  false
consists_class:                   false
consists_union:                   false
consists_variable:                false
consists_function:                false
consists_overloaded_func:         false
consists_reference:               false
consists_t_alias:                 true
consists_t_struct:                true
consists_t_class:                 true
consists_t_union:                 true
consists_t_variable:              false
consists_t_function:              false
consists_t_overloaded_function:   false
consists_s_variable:              false
consists_s_function:              false
consists_s_overloaded_func:       false
consists_s_t_function:            false
consists_s_t_overloaded_function: false

--Has member function template bar---
consists_no_bar:                  false
consists_alias:                   false
consists_struct:                  false
consists_class:                   false
consists_union:                   false
consists_variable:                false
consists_function:                false
consists_overloaded_func:         true // implmementation bug
consists_reference:               false
consists_t_alias:                 false
consists_t_struct:                false
consists_t_class:                 false
consists_t_union:                 false
consists_t_variable:              false
consists_t_function:              true
consists_t_overloaded_function:   true
consists_s_variable:              false
consists_s_function:              false
consists_s_overloaded_func:       true // implmementation bug
consists_s_t_function:            true
consists_s_t_overloaded_function: true

--Has member variable template bar---
consists_no_bar:                  false
consists_alias:                   false
consists_struct:                  false
consists_class:                   false
consists_union:                   false
consists_variable:                false
consists_function:                false
consists_overloaded_func:         false
consists_reference:               false
consists_t_alias:                 false
consists_t_struct:                false
consists_t_class:                 false
consists_t_union:                 false
consists_t_variable:              true
consists_t_function:              false
consists_t_overloaded_function:   false
consists_s_variable:              false
consists_s_function:              false
consists_s_overloaded_func:       false
consists_s_t_function:            false
consists_s_t_overloaded_function: false

--Has any member template bar---
consists_no_bar:                  false
consists_alias:                   false
consists_struct:                  false
consists_class:                   false
consists_union:                   false
consists_variable:                false
consists_function:                false
consists_overloaded_func:         true // implmementation bug
consists_reference:               false
consists_t_alias:                 true
consists_t_struct:                true
consists_t_class:                 true
consists_t_union:                 true
consists_t_variable:              true
consists_t_function:              true
consists_t_overloaded_function:   true
consists_s_variable:              false
consists_s_function:              false
consists_s_overloaded_func:       true // implmementation bug
consists_s_t_function:            true
consists_s_t_overloaded_function: true
```

I'm still sad that I couldn't detect overloaded functions... But it was fun :)