# Is there any way of detecting arbitrary template classes that mix types and non-types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, type-traits

Is there any way of detecting whether a class is a normal type or is an instantiation of a template type (meta type) **which may include non-type parameters**? I came up with this solution:

```
#include <iostream>

template <template<class...> class> 
constexpr bool is_template()
{
    return true;
}

template <class> 
constexpr bool is_template()
{
    return false;
}

struct Foo{};

template<class> struct TemplateFoo{};

template<class, int> struct MixedFoo{};

int main()
{
     std::cout << std::boolalpha;
     std::cout << is_template<Foo>() << std::endl;  
     std::cout << is_template<TemplateFoo>() << std::endl;  
     // std::cout << is_template<MixedFoo>() << std::endl; // fails here
}
```

however it will fail for templates that mix non-types and types, like

```
template<class, int> struct MixedFoo{};
```

I am not able to come up with any solution, except the one in which I must explicitly specify the types in the overloads. Of course this is un-reasonable due to combinatorial explosion.

Related question (not a dupe): [Is it possible to check for existence of member templates just by an identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39811895/3093378)

Comment: Sadly [not even C++17](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VAUXmYQ6tM5L2GOh) seems to reduce the required number of combinations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is not.

Note that template classes are not classes themselves.  They are templates for classes.

Comment: Yes, I know that template classes are not types themselves but meta types. Still, one can distinguish them from normal types, except in the case where they take non-type parameters. I thought that maybe someone can come up with a way of doing it.

Comment: @vsoft I added 2nd paragraph because of a minor error in your question (where you refer to a template class as a class), but mainly because first paragraph was too short for an answer.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is not possible.

Anyway, you can use the other way around and let `N` be deduced:

```
template<class, class> struct MixedFoo;
template<class C, int N> struct MixedFoo<C, std::integral_constant<int, N>>{};
```

Now, this returns `true` as expected:

```
 std::cout << is_template<MixedFoo>() << std::endl; // fails here
```

Of course, you won't be able anymore to use `MixedFoo` as `MixedFoo<int, 2>`, so I'm not sure it's worth it.