# Transpose a container of structs

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++17, variadic-templates

Let we have a `struct Record{uint8_t x, y;};`, a container `Container<Record>` of structs and a `struct Transposed{Container<uint8_t> x,y};`. Container `c` is a template which first arg is a type of value, all of the rest args have default values. For example it can be a `std::vector` (the rest args are types) or `std::span` (the rest arg is a value). The template should work with all of them. Also we may like to pass tne rest of template arguments to underlying template.

How we can get the `Transposed` from the container using templates?

I have tried variadic templates,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename value_type=uint8_t> struct Record{
    value_type x, y;
};

template<typename value_type, typename value_type2=uint8_t> class ContainerA: public std::vector<value_type>{
    value_type2 b=1u;
};

template<typename value_type, uint8_t int_value=1u> class ContainerB: public std::vector<value_type>{};

template<typename value_type, template <typename ...> typename container_type> class Transposed{
    container_type<value_type> x, y;

    public:
        Transposed(container_type<Record<value_type>> & recs){
            x.reserve(recs.size());
            y.reserve(recs.size());
            x.resize(recs.size());
            y.resize(recs.size());
            size_t i=0;
            for(auto &rec :recs){
                x[i] = rec.x;
                y[i] = rec.y;
                ++i;
            }
        }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<Record<uint8_t>> recsV{
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4}
    };
    Transposed trV{recsV};
    std::cout<<"vec"<<std::endl;

    ContainerA<Record<uint8_t>> recsA{
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4}
    };
    Transposed trA{recsA};
    std::cout<<"A"<<std::endl;

    /*ContainerB<Record<uint8_t>> recsB{
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4}
    };
    Transposed trB{recsB};
    std::cout<<"B"<<std::endl;*/
    return 0;
}
```

but it seems they cannot match both types and values. Usage of more than 1 variadic template argument is not allowed. Is it a flaw in C++ language or a deliberate design choice and do we need something like `any_template_arg` keyword or should just specifying 2 variadic arguments of different types be allowed to allow this use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way of detecting arbitrary template classes that mix types and non-types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812789/is-there-any-way-of-detecting-arbitrary-template-classes-that-mix-types-and-non)

Comment: Not quite. I have already read this question. Now the questions are if it is a design flaw in C++ and if we should fix it and how we should fix it.

Comment: Well, judging the design of C++ is opinion-based (hence off topic for Stack Overflow) and that question already addresses how to fix it (you pretty much can't do that in a general way, but you can specialize for the specific containers).

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, there isn't a way to match types and values (and template-template) template arguments together. And I've searched it for a long time.

So I don't see a way to make what do you want in a simple and elegant way.

Trying to respond to your question

> How we can get the `Transposed` from the container using templates?

the best I can imagine is declare (isn't necessary define them taking in count are used only inside a `decltype()`) a couple of trivial functions as follows

```
template <typename VT,
          template <typename...> typename CT>
CT<VT> extract_func (CT<Record<VT>>);

template <typename VT,
          template <typename, auto...> typename CT>
CT<VT> extract_func (CT<Record<VT>>);
```

The first one is to remove the `Record` part when the `CT` container accepts a variadic list of types (`std::vector` and `ContainerA` cases); the second one is for `CT` containers accepting (after the type parameter) one or more values (`ContainerB` case).

Obviously this doen't cover all possible cases, but it's trivial declare other `extract_func()` functions to cover other cases.

Now you can declare `Tranposed` as follows

```
template <typename T,
          typename CT = decltype(extract_func(std::declval<T>()))>
class Transposed
```

Observe that, now, `Transposed` accept a generic type `T` but is SFINAE enabled only when the `T` type matches (as argument) an `extract_func()` declaration.

In the `Transposed` body you can use `CT` to declare `x` and `y` and `T` for the argument of the constructor.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename value_type=std::uint8_t>
struct Record
 { value_type x, y; };

template <typename value_type, typename value_type2=std::uint8_t>
class ContainerA : public std::vector<value_type>
 { value_type2 b=1u; };

template <typename value_type, std::uint8_t int_value=1u>
class ContainerB : public std::vector<value_type>
 { };

template <typename VT,
          template <typename...> typename CT>
CT<VT> extract_func (CT<Record<VT>>);

template <typename VT,
          template <typename, auto...> typename CT>
CT<VT> extract_func (CT<Record<VT>>);

template <typename T,
          typename CT = decltype(extract_func(std::declval<T>()))>
class Transposed
 {
   private:
      CT x, y;

   public:
      Transposed (T & recs)
       {
         x.reserve(recs.size());
         y.reserve(recs.size());
         x.resize(recs.size());
         y.resize(recs.size());
         std::size_t i=0u;
         for(auto &rec :recs){
            x[i] = rec.x;
            y[i] = rec.y;
            ++i;
         }
       }
 };

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<Record<std::uint8_t>> recsV { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };

   Transposed trV{recsV};

   std::cout<<"vec"<<std::endl;

   ContainerA<Record<std::uint8_t>> recsA { };

   Transposed trA{recsA};

   std::cout<<"A"<<std::endl;

   ContainerB<Record<std::uint8_t>> recsB { };

   Transposed trB{recsB};

   std::cout<<"B"<<std::endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

One working example for you:

```
template<typename value_type=uint8_t>
struct Record{
    value_type x, y;
};

template<class T>
std::vector<T> rebind_container(std::vector<Record<T>> const&);

// Span transposes into vector.
template<class T>
std::vector<T> rebind_container(std::span<Record<T>> const&); 

template<class T>
std::list<T> rebind_container(std::list<Record<T>> const&);

inline void reserve(...) {}

template<class... Args>
inline void reserve(std::vector<Args...>* v, size_t n) {
    v->reserve(n);
}

template<class container_type>
struct Transposed {
    using container_type2 = decltype(rebind_container(std::declval<container_type>()));

    container_type2 x, y;

    Transposed(container_type const& recs) {
        auto const n = recs.size();
        reserve(&x, n);
        reserve(&y, n);
        for(auto& rec : recs) {
            x.push_back(rec.x);
            y.push_back(rec.y);
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<Record<uint8_t>> recsV{
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4}
    };
    Transposed<decltype(recsV)> trV{recsV};
    std::cout << trV.x.size() << std::endl;

    std::list<Record<uint8_t>> recsV2{
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4}
    };
    Transposed<decltype(recsV2)> trV2{recsV2};
    std::cout << trV2.x.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That's `vector` only.  The question is asking for a generic one.

Comment: @L.F. True. You need to add `rebind_container` functions for different containers, as well as different specialisations of `Transposed` for different containers (e.g. `std::list` doesn't have `reserve` and indexed access). `std::span` won't work for you because it doesn't own storage.

Comment: @KOLANICH It works for `vector` and `list`. That should be enough for you to see how to support other containers you may want. `std::span` won't work for you because it doesn't store anything.

Comment: Yeah, std::span doesn't have reserve, so it requires specialization. But it doesn't change the main problem of the question - inability to match templates against any template.

Comment: @KOLANICH You can use `std::span` as input only. Added a specialization for you, as another example.