# Is there any way to detect overloaded member function by name alone? (not to detect name)

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, overloading, member-functions

I am wishful here, but I want to be precise about the question. I want to improve implementation of detecting member templates by their names alone, but I came across an obstacle. I can't find any way to detect overloaded `static`/non-`static` member functions. Very important part of this question is, that I can't use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3102261/5405086), because it detects any name (I'm already using it in current implementation, kinda useful), and I can't specify the types, because that misses the point of using names alone.

For reference, see my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39811895/5405086). I posted current `has_member_template_bar` implementation as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39820685/5405086) there. I don't think I should post all of it in this question.

The question stays the same - Can we detect overloaded member functions, without specifying their arguments, or using mentioned trick? I know I'm maybe asking for impossible, but it never hurts to ask.

Comment: Interesting question, it was funny to find a way to do that. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question stays the same - Can we detect overloaded member functions, without specifying their arguments, or using mentioned trick? I know I'm maybe asking for impossible, but it never hurts to ask

Actually, it is not impossible.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename... A>
void proto(R(T::*)(A...));

template<typename, typename = void>
constexpr bool has_single_f = false;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool has_single_f<T, decltype(proto(&T::f))> = true;

struct S {
    void f(int) {}
    void f(char) {}
};

struct U {
    void f() {}
};

int main() {
    static_assert(not has_single_f<S>, "!");
    static_assert(has_single_f<U>, "!");
}
```

Of course, you need to add more stuff to distinguish between member methods and data members, but it's trivial to add them (see the header `type_traits`) and I tried to keep the example as minimal as possible.

The basic idea is that the call to `proto` fails if the given function is overloaded, for it's an *ambiguous call*.
Anyway, the error is discarded because of SFINAE rules.
Arguments are not required to be specified as requested.
Note also that `proto` does not require to be defined, but it's important that its return type is `void`. Otherwise you have to slightly modify the call to `decltype` as it follows:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool has_single_f<T, decltype(proto(&T::f), void())> = true;
```

As you can see from the example code, the `static_assert`s verify that `f` is overloaded in `S` and it is not in `U`.

---

The example above is based on template variables, that are part of the language since C++14.
If you prefer the well known struct based solution that works with C++11, you can use the following detector:

```
#include<type_traits>

//...

template<typename, typename = void>
struct has_single_f: std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_single_f<T, decltype(proto(&T::f))>: std::true_type {};

//...

int main() {
    static_assert(not has_single_f<S>::value, "!");
    static_assert(has_single_f<U>::value, "!");
}
```

Comment: I'm starting to feel that nothing is impossible with templates :) . Great answer!