# Detect if C++ class has a template method

Tags: c++, templates, generics, c++17

I know how to detect presence of a variable or a regular method in a C++ class. But how to do it, when the method is a template? Consider the code:

```
struct SomeClass
{
    template<typename Sender, typename T>
    auto& send(T& object) const
    {
        Sender::send(object);
        return object;
    };
};
```

How to write something like `is_sendable` so that `is_sendable<SomeClass>::value` (or any other syntax) returns true because `SomeClass` has method `send` like above ?

Comment: `SomeClass::send<some_sender,some_type>` is a method (not a template). Do you want to detect if `SomeClass::send` is a template or do you want to detect if `SomeClass::send` can be called for some specific  `Sender` and `T` ?

Comment: Possibly relevant ....   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811895/is-it-possible-to-check-for-existence-of-member-templates-just-by-an-identifier

Comment: If you use `C++20` then language feature `concept` was added to deal with such tasks. If you don't then there are various complicated workarounds with SFINAE.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I want to detect if `SomeClass` has a method `SomeClass::send` that is callable with any `Sender` and any `T` (not a specific one) (or at least any `T`).

Comment: @ALX23z Unfortunately, at this moment only up C++17.

Comment: While there are some convoluted methods that can test whether some method can be called, it is much easier to simply add a field that indicates whether that class is a "sender". Declare some alias `using sender = void;` and if the type `sender` exists then presume that it is a sender. Also you can write your own type trait for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I acutally managed to solve it, if anyone is interested:

I needed to create a dummy class

```
class DummySender
{
    public:
        template<typename T>
        static void send(const T&)
        {}
};
```

And then I can check for the presence of the send method, by defining type traits:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct IsSendable: std::false_type
{};

template<typename T>
struct IsSendable<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().send<DummySender>(std::cout), void())> : std::true_type
{};
```

To finally have `IsSendable<SomeClass>::value`.