# Use of void template argument in early detection idiom implementation

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-meta-programming, c++17

In [n4502](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf) the authors describe an early implementation of the detect idiom that encapsulates the `void_t` trick. Here's its definition along with usage for defining a trait for `is_assignable` (really it's `is_copy_assignable`)

```
template<class...>
using void_t = void;

// primary template handles all types not supporting the operation:
template< class, template<class> class, class = void_t< > >
struct
detect : std::false_type { };
// specialization recognizes/validates only types supporting the archetype:
template< class T, template<class> class Op >
struct
detect< T, Op, void_t<Op<T>> > : std::true_type { };

// archetypal expression for assignment operation:
template< class T >
using
assign_t = decltype( std::declval<T&>() = std::declval<T const &>() );

// trait corresponding to that archetype:
template< class T >
using
is_assignable = detect<void, assign_t, T>;
```

They mention that they don't like this because of the `void` used in the `is_assignable` trait:

> Although the resulting code was significantly more comprehensible than
>   the original, we disliked the above detect interface because the `void`
>   argument in the metafunction call is an implementation detail that
>   shouldn’t leak out to client code.

However, the `void` doesn't make any sense to me in the first place. If I try to use this type trait to detect if `int` is copy assignable, I get `std::false_type` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9e5f6da4e062946).

If I rewrite `is_assignable` as:

```
template< class T >
using
is_assignable = detect<T, assign_t>;
```

Which makes more sense to me, then the trait appears to work correctly: 
[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7192615a927fb82c)

So my question here is **Am I misunderstanding something in this document, or was it simply a typo?**

If it *was* a typo, then I don't understand why the authors felt the need to discuss how they didn't like `void` leaking out, which makes me pretty sure I'm just missing something.

Comment: N4502's predecessor, [N4436](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4436.pdf), has even more egregious typos (incorrect number of template arguments). So another set of typos would not be out of the question... ;-]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `using is_assignable = detect<T, assign_t, void>` instead?

Comment: @Rerito I don't think the trailing `void` is necessary. I believe the root cause of the confusion is due to a typo, as suggested by Ildjarn. As the author mentions in the footnotes of the paper, perhaps this is a "thinko"

Comment: @Rerito: Thanks for that. Can you come up with a scenario where the `void` is necessary?

Comment: @SteveLorimer I pointed out the said typo ;)

Comment: The trailing void in that case is unnecessary since the default template argument is specified in the non-specialized template.

Comment: @Rerito: Agreed. So I'm scratching my head as to why the authors chose that reason for reworking the idiom. I think perhaps a better argument could be made that they wanted to support `detected_t` that would give the type of `Op<Args...>`

Comment: @AndyG I thought the same, maybe [an actual example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30195655/1794345) would help

Comment: @Rerito: It looks like @Yakk's answer does require the `void` because of variadic template usage. Perhaps this scenario is what the authors had in mind rather than the simplistic single type [Here's what I mean](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa4f26858ef31f1f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging on how the authors wrote their final implementation of `is_detected`, they intended that `Op` be a variadic template, which allows one to express many more concepts:

(Also pulled from [n4502](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf))

```
// primary template handles all types not supporting the archetypal Op:
template< class Default
, class // always void; supplied externally
, template<class...> class Op
, class... Args
>
struct
detector
{
  using value_t = false_type;
  using type = Default;
};
// the specialization recognizes and handles only types supporting Op:
template< class Default
, template<class...> class Op
, class... Args
>
struct
detector<Default, void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...>
{
  using value_t = true_type;
  using type = Op<Args...>;
};
//...
template< template<class...> class Op, class... Args >
using
is_detected = typename detector<void, void, Op, Args...>::value_t;
```

When you get into a scenario like this, a `void` becomes necessary so that template specialization will match the `true_type` version when `Op<Args...>` is a valid expression.

[Here's my tweak on the original detect to be variadic](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fFY3gM8IFjBMQCPn):

```
// primary template handles all types not supporting the operation:
template< class T, template<class...> class Trait, class... TraitArgs >
struct
detect : std::false_type { };
// specialization recognizes/validates only types supporting the archetype:
template< class T, template<class...> class Trait, class... TraitArgs >
struct
detect< T, Trait, std::void_t<Trait<T, TraitArgs...>>, TraitArgs... > : std::true_type { };

template<class T, template<class...> class Trait, class... TraitArgs>
using is_detected_t = typename detect<T, Trait, void, TraitArgs...>::type; 

template<class T, template<class...> class Trait, class... TraitArgs>
constexpr bool is_detected_v = detect<T, Trait, void, TraitArgs...>::value;
```

Note that I renamed `Op` to `Trait`, `Args` to `TraitArgs`, and used [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) which made it into C++17.

Now let's define a trait to test for a function named  `Foo` that can may or may not accept certain parameter types:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
using HasFoo_t = decltype( std::declval<T>().Foo(std::declval<Args>()...));
```

Now we can get a type (`true_type` or `false_type`) given some `T` and our trait:

```
template< class T, class... Args>
using has_foo_t = is_detected_t<T, HasFoo_t, Args...>;
```

And finally, we can also "just check" to see if the trait is valid for some provided `T` and `Args`:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
constexpr bool has_foo_v = is_detected_v<T, HasFoo_t, Args...>;
```

Here's a struct to start testing:

```
struct A
{
    void Foo(int)
    {
        std::cout << "A::Foo(int)\n";
    }
};
```

And finally the test(s):

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_foo_v<A, int> << std::endl; //true
std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_foo_v<A> << std::endl; // false
```

If I remove the `void` from my `is_detected_t` and `is_detected_v` implementations, then the primary specialization is chosen, and I get `false` ([Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yHn2CEPkoMSqPCds)).

This is because the `void` is there so as to match `std::void_t<Trait<T, TraitArgs...>>` which if you recall will have a type of `void` if the template argument is well-formed. If the template argument is not well-formed, then `std::void_t<Trait<T, TraitArgs...>>` is not a good match and it will revert to the default specialization (`false_type`).

When we remove `void` from our call (and simply leave `TraitArgs...` in its place) then we cannot match the `std::void_t<Trait<T, TraitArgs...>>` argument in the `true_type` specialization.

Also note that if `std::void_t<Trait<T, TraitArgs...>>` is well-formed, it simply provides a `void` type to the `class... TraitArgs` argument in the primary template, so we don't need to define an extra template parameter to receive `void`.

In conclusion, the authors wanted to remove the `void` that would end up in client code, hence their slightly more complicated implementation later in the paper.

Thanks to @Rerito for pointing out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30195655/27678) where Yakk also puts in a little extra work to avoid the pesky `void` in client code.

Comment: If this guy wants to get something approved like this, shouldn't s/he get it proof read and tested? Very annoying for the readers.