# How can I gate template function definition based on whether a template parameter pack matches function arguments?

Tags: c++, overloading, variadic-functions, function-parameter, function-templates

Lets sat that I have 2 functions:

```
int foo(const int, const float);
int bar(const int, const char);
```

Now I want to overload a veradic template function based on whether it matches one of these functions. So for example:

```
template <typename... T>
decltype(foo(declval<T>()...) func(T... args);

template <typename... T>
decltype(bar(declval<T>()...) func(T... args);
```

But I'm getting the error:

> error C2995: 'unknown-type func(T...)': function template has already been defined

Because the `T` must be defined differently for each I would have assumed this was a valid overload, but it seems like it's not :( Can someone help me allow this overload?

Comment: What should happen for `func('a', 'b')`? Both `foo('a', 'b')` and `bar('a', 'b')` are valid calls.

Comment: `tag dispatch` ? You can't overload based on a single typename, from the compiler's point of view they are identical. Introduce another template parameter, add a tag for each of the functions by introducing a unique type and then dispatch

Comment: @KostasRim I'm not certain I understand the statement "You can't overload based on a single typename" You're saying that the actual function declarations don't boil down to `int func(int, float)` and `int func(int, char)` in the compiler?

Comment: @JonathanMee no all I am saying that this `template <typename... T>
decltype(foo(declval<T...>()) func(T... args);` is the same as this `template <typename... T>
decltype(bar(declval<T...>()) func(T... args);` and they differ only in what they return. That is, `T is a placeholder, not a concrete type`. That's why you need to tag dispatch. Basically you redefining the same template with a different return statement

Comment: @KostasRim they should trigger SFINAE and thus only one should be defined.

Comment: @JonathanMee Edit, my bad, sorry I thought the two functions return different type. You are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you call `func(0,0)`.  During overload resolution both of these are considered:

```
template <typename... T>
decltype(foo(declval<T>()...) func(T... args);

template <typename... T>
decltype(bar(declval<T>()...) func(T... args);
```

substitution is done:

```
template <typename... T = {int, int}>
decltype(foo(declval<int>(),declval<int>()) func(int,  int);

template <typename... T = {int, int}>
decltype(bar(declval<int>(),declval<int>()) func(int, int);
```

`foo` and `bar` calls are evaluated, then `decltype`'d:

```
template <typename... T = {int, int}>
int func(int,  int);

template <typename... T = {int, int}>
int func(int, int);
```

notice that these are identical signatures.  The compiler complains, you aren't allowed to do this.

How you got to identical signatures is, in a sense, immaterial.

You *can* write a trait that reads "you can call `bar` with these arguments".  Suppose you do it.

```
template<class...Ts>
constexpr bool can_call_bar_with = /* some expression */;
```

and

```
template<class...Ts>
constexpr bool can_call_foo_with = /* some expression */;
```

now we can do this:

```
template <typename... T,
  std::enable_if_t< can_call_foo_with<T...>, bool> = true
>
int func(T... args);

template <typename... T,
  std::enable_if_t< can_call_bar_with<T...> && ! can_call_foo_with<T...>, bool> = true
>
int func(T... args);
```

and now no matter what `T...` you pass to it, you never get two `func`; this is because I ensured that SFINAE makes only one signature valid.

To write

```
template<class...Ts>
constexpr bool can_call_bar_with = /* some expression */;
```

there is the `is_detected` or my `can_apply` idiom.
  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30189926/1774667).

---

If you want to ask "which, between `foo` and `bar, would be preferred in overload resolution", that is a different and more difficult problem.  There is no general way; with a list of signatures, you can do it.

//you'd implement this something like:

```
template<class...Ts>
struct types_t {};


template<std::size_t I, class Sig>
struct make_tagged_sig;
template<std::size_t I, class Sig>
using tagged_sig = typename make_tagged_sig<I,Sig>::type;

template<std::size_t I, class...Ts>
struct make_tagged_sig<I, types_t<Ts...>> {
  using type=std::integral_constant<std::size_t,I>(Ts...);
};


template<class Sig>
struct overload_check;

template<class R, class...Args>
struct overload_check<R(Args...)> {
  R test(Args...) const;
};

template<class...Sigs>
struct overload_checker:
  overload_check<Sigs>...
{
  using overload_check<Sigs>::test...;

  template<class...Args>
  constexpr auto operator()( types_t<Args...> ) const {
    return decltype( test( std::declval<Args>()... ) ){};
  }
};

template<class Indexes, class...Sigs>
struct which_overload_helper;
template<class...Sigs>
using which_overload_helper_t = typename which_overload_helper<std::index_sequence_for<Sigs...>, Sigs...>::type;
template<std::size_t...Is, class...Sigs>
struct which_overload_helper<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Sigs...> {
    using type = overload_checker< tagged_sig<Is, Sigs>... >;
};

template<class Args, class...Sigs>
constexpr std::size_t which_overload = which_overload_helper_t<Sigs...>{}( Args{} );
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e50046cf5b9e98f).

Comment: But I *don't* call `func(0,0)` I call `func(0, 0.0F)` In which case only one should be defined... right?

Comment: @JonathanMee do you declare and define the template later or is it a definition inside the header ?

Comment: @JonathanMee `0.F` can convert to `char` no problem.  So `decltype( bar(0, 0.F) )` is `int`.

Comment: I guess I'm confused because If I write: `int func(int, float)` and `int func(int, char)` and call `func(0, 0.0F)` that is *not* ambiguous, why then would it be in the template case? Anyway, I need to read your updated answer now...

Comment: @JonathanMee You may intend your code to say "do overload resolution between `foo` and `bar`", but that isn't what *your code says*, and your code does what it says not what you mean it to say.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont So traits are my workaround. Not what I was hoping for, but the answer does make sense. Thank you for the explanation I'll accept shortly...

Comment: @JonathanMee "Which overload" template written.  It is probably what you want.