# Do Manipulators Convert the Stream Type Somehow?

Tags: c++, stringstream, anonymous, static-cast, manipulators

I'm trying to use an anonymous `ostringstream` to generate a `string`: [Use an Anonymous Stringstream to Construct a String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19665458/2642059)

However when I use manipulators I can't seem to compile any longer:

```
const auto myString(static_cast<ostringstream>(ostringstream{} << setfill('!') << setw(13) << "lorem ipsum").str());
```

But that doesn't seem to be allowed [even in gcc 5.1](http://ideone.com/CZjGzS):

> prog.cpp: In function `int main()`:
>   prog.cpp:8:109: error: no matching function for call to `std::basic_ostringstream<char>::basic_ostringstream(std::basic_ostream<char>&)`
>     `const auto myString(static_cast<ostringstream>(ostringstream{} << setfill('!') << setw(13) << "lorem ipsum").str());` 
>   
>   In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iomanip:45:0,
>                    from prog.cpp:1:
>   /usr/include/c++/5/sstream:582:7: note: candidate
>   `std::basic_ostringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_ostringstream(std::basic_ostringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&)` [with `_CharT = char`; `_Traits = std::char_traits<char>`; `_Alloc = std::allocator<char>`]
>          `basic_ostringstream(basic_ostringstream&& __rhs)`
>   
>   /usr/include/c++/5/sstream:582:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from `std::basic_ostream<char>` to `std::basic_ostringstream<char>&&`
>   /usr/include/c++/5/sstream:565:7: note: candidate:
>   `std::basic_ostringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_ostringstream(const __string_type&, std::ios_base::openmode)` [with `_CharT = char`; `_Traits = std::char_traits<char>`; `_Alloc = std::allocator<char>`; `std::basic_ostringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::__string_type = std::basic_string<char>`; `std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode`]
>          `basic_ostringstream(const __string_type& __str,`
>   
>   /usr/include/c++/5/sstream:565:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from `std::basic_ostream<char>` to `const __string_type& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}`
>   /usr/include/c++/5/sstream:547:7: note: candidate: 
>   `std::basic_ostringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_ostringstream(std::ios_base::openmode)` [with `_CharT = char`; `_Traits = std::char_traits<char>`; `_Alloc = std::allocator<char>`; `std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode`]
>          `basic_ostringstream(ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::out)`
>   
>   /usr/include/c++/5/sstream:547:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from `std::basic_ostream<char>` to `std::ios_base::openmode {aka std::_Ios_Openmode}`

Is this another gcc stream bug, or is what I'm doing actually illegal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static_cast<ostringstream>(...)
```

This will try to construct a new `ostringstream` from the argument in the parens, a `std::ostream&`, for which there is no constructor of [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/basic_ostringstream).

You just want to cast the reference back to the original type. Make the cast to a reference:

```
static_cast<ostringstream&>(...)
```

Then it works fine.

I don't know what you thought worked, but leaving out the reference, and removing the manipulators, it still fails.

Comment: Well now I feel dumb. Thanks for catching my missing reference.