# Temporary in a function call: UB?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Consider the following code, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19665604/1683161):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class StringBuilder {
public:
    template <typename T> inline StringBuilder &operator<<(T const &t) {
        ss << t;
        return *this;
    }

    inline char const * c_str() {
        return ss.str().c_str();
    }

private:
    std::stringstream ss;
};

void foo(const char *x) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    foo((StringBuilder() << "testing " << 12 << 3 << 4).c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Does calling `foo()` with the temporary `StringBuilder`'s return value cause UB in any way?

The reason I'm asking is that the example above works great, but in real life I'm using a library that, amongst other things, contains logging facilities, and using this library I'll get incorrect output (the logging function takes my `char*` correctly but overwrites it internally, which caused me to believe that the memory is no longer valid).

Comment: You have UB in `return ss.str().c_str();` See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034834/is-there-issue-will-stringstream-str-c-str

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but not because of what you perhaps think.

The temporary `StringBuilder` in the function call is not destroyed until after `foo` returns, so that's fine.

However, the `c_str()` method returns the result of calling `.str().c_str()`, and the temporary string returned by this `str()` is destroyed as `StringBuilder::c_str()` returns, which means that the pointer returned is invalid outside. Using this pointer causes UB.

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense, I missed the point that `stringstream::str()` returned a the string as a copy. Is there any way to fix my `StringBuilder`, other than copying `ss.str()`'s result into another `string` in my class or using `(StringBuilder () << 1).str().c_str()`?

Comment: Why does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006891/stdstringc-str-and-temporaries) say the opposite? Why are there two deleted answers here?

Comment: @LogicStuff The linked question is different because in that situation, the temporary `std::string` isn't destroyed before the pointer is used. And I can only guess about the two deleted answers, but since they were both posted and deleted while I was writing mine, I would guess that they only looked at the line in `main`, saw nothing wrong with it, and then deleted their answers after seeing `Hayt`'s comment (also posted while I was writing my answer, and containing the core issue).

Comment: @SebastianRedl Wow, even I've missed what `StringBuilder::c_str` is actually doing...